# VS Code keyboard mapping is messed up. How to reset/change?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It seems that my VS Code keyboard mapping is incorrect.  At first I thought it was a keybinding issue but when I try to change keybindings I notice that the names of the keys VS Code says I'm typing in for the keybind are different from what I'm actually typing.  For instance, my backspace key does not delete left as it should.  When I try to change the delete left keybind I see that it is already marked as "backspace".  When I try to change the keybind, I see that VS Code thinks my Backspace key is actually Alt.  I suspect that my keyboard mapping is incorrectly set (perhaps it's set to international or similar). I think the problem is specific to VS Code since I can type normally in terminal.

[keybinding example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN19u.png)

Does anyone know how to fix or reset the keyboard mapping in VS Code v1.67.0 for linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're running into this issue documented here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/50756

The relevant setting to add in your user settings.json is:

`keyboard.dispatch: "keyCode"`